# Inner Arraylist<Hashmap> display null at the end after adding in android?

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap

i am accessing data from database and store in arraylist but at the end i display complete list it display null

> Output :
>
> 09-01 17:26:49.550: E/data(16620): ---->15
>
> 09-01 17:26:49.550: > E/data(16620): ---->[[], [], [], [], [], [], [],
>   [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> testdata(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
         int count=0;
         int k=0;
         ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> data =
                 new ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>>();
         ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> odata =
                 new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

         String Query=
          "SELECT * FROM myfiles "+
          "WHERE (( Datetime('2014-09-01 09:50:15') >= startdate " +
            "AND Datetime('2014-09-01 09:50:15') <= enddate ) " +
            "AND ( " +
                "('09:50:15' >= strftime('%H:%M:%S',timer_from) " +
                "AND '09:50:15' <= strftime('%H:%M:%S',timer_to )) " +
                "OR ( strftime('%H:%M:%S',timer_from) = '00:00:00' " +
                    "OR '00:00:00' = strftime('%H:%M:%S',timer_to )))) " +
            "AND ( Monday = 1 OR Everyday = 1) AND download = 1 " +
            "AND playlist_id = 24 AND user_id='83' " +
          "ORDER BY position_id ASC, subposition_id ASC";

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(Query, null);
        if(cursor.getCount()<=0)
        {
            cursor.close();
            return data;
        }          
        else
        {
             if (cursor.moveToFirst()) 
             {
                 do 
                 {
                     HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                     String currenttype=cursor.getString(9);
                     String nexttype = null;
                     if(count<cursor.getCount())
                     {   
                         if(cursor.getPosition()==cursor.getCount()-1)
                         {   

                             nexttype="image";
                         }  
                         else
                         {
                             cursor.moveToNext(); 
                             nexttype=cursor.getString(9);
                             cursor.moveToPrevious(); 
                         }

                     }
                     map.put(DB_Constant.MYFILES.FILE_ID, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_Constant.MYFILES.FILE_ID)));
                     map.put(DB_Constant.MYFILES.FILE_TYPE, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_Constant.MYFILES.FILE_TYPE)));
                     map.put(DB_Constant.MYFILES.FILE_SUBTYPE, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_Constant.MYFILES.FILE_SUBTYPE)));
                     map.put(DB_Constant.MYFILES.FILE_PATH, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_Constant.MYFILES.FILE_PATH)));
                     map.put(DB_Constant.MYFILES.USERID, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_Constant.MYFILES.USERID)));
                     map.put(DB_Constant.MYFILES.FILE_SECOND, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_Constant.MYFILES.FILE_SECOND)));
                     map.put(DB_Constant.MYFILES.FILE_DOWNLOAD, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_Constant.MYFILES.FILE_DOWNLOAD)));
                     map.put(DB_Constant.MYFILES.FILE_STARTTIME, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_Constant.MYFILES.FILE_STARTTIME)));
                     map.put(DB_Constant.MYFILES.FILE_ENDTIME, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_Constant.MYFILES.FILE_ENDTIME)));
                     map.put(DB_Constant.MYFILES.FILE_TIMERFROM, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_Constant.MYFILES.FILE_TIMERFROM)));
                     map.put(DB_Constant.MYFILES.FILE_TIMERTO, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_Constant.MYFILES.FILE_TIMERTO)));
                     map.put(DB_Constant.MYFILES.FILE_STUDIOFORMAT, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_Constant.MYFILES.FILE_STUDIOFORMAT)));
                     odata.add(map);

                     if(currenttype.equalsIgnoreCase("image") || 
                        currenttype.equalsIgnoreCase("video"))
                     {
                         data.add(odata);
                         odata.clear();
                     }
                     else if(nexttype.equalsIgnoreCase("image") || 
                        nexttype.equalsIgnoreCase("video"))
                     {
                         data.add(odata);
                         odata.clear();
                     }
                     count++;
                 } while (cursor.moveToNext());
             }
         }   
        Log.e("data","---->"+data.size());
        Log.e("data","---->"+data);
        cursor.close();
        return data;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add an element to a Map, a List or a Set, the original object is added, no copy is created, so if you modify it, it is modified within the collection. Simple example:

```
class Foo {
  public int bar;
}
```

using that simple class in another piece of code...

```
List<Foo> myList= new ArrayList<>();

Foo f= new Foo(); //we create a Foo object, and f is a variable that references it
f.bar=9; 
myList.add(f);  //we add the object to the list
```

So now we have two references to this object: `f` and `myList.get(0)`. If you do:

```
f.bar=15;
```

then

```
System.out.println(myList.get(0))
```

will show `15` in your screen.

In your code you are reusing the same object. Instead calling `clear()`, create a new object:

```
odata = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
```

In sum: you can reuse a variable, but in that case you cannot reuse the referenced object.

Comment: thanks works for me  odata = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

Comment: hello need one more  help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25622025/round-looping-not-work-in-arraylist-with-hashmap-for-display-images

Answer (score 0):

You have successfully added your hashmap to your list. **And the count shows 15 as well**. The only problem is, you are not being able to either store correctly on hash map or display correctly

Comment: but i have cleared arraylist after adding than why it was affect on my main list

Comment: what do you mean by "main list"?

Comment: ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> data = new ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>>(); is main list

Comment: Are you sure you have correct query? And are you sure _cursor.getCount()<=0_ is false?

Comment: check this here i display complete play list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60399/discussion-between-mahesh-and-nabin).